# WCF "Global" Operation Invoker

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-client

Here is what I want to achieve. In a IIS hosted WCF service I would like to be able to read the incoming message headers and based on a specific header value perform some custom actions. This header reading should take place before any web service method is executed. 
Can you please provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention what you want to do with a message headers so perhaps it will not satisfy your needs but you can try using custom [message inspector](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx).

Comment: Well, I need to read the header value (e.g.: header name is 'auth-token', header value is 'mytoken'), and based on that (if the token is a valid one) I have to execute or not the contract operation.